# Fatal error: Call to undefined method Mage_Adminhtml_Model_System_Config_Source_Yesno::setAttribute() in Abstract.php on line 389

Tags: php, magento

I've looked everywhere and can't find how to fix this error. It doesn't show up in any error logs I'm aware of. I can only see it if I look at the page source. It completely stops the page from rendering half way through. How can I fix this?

Comment: well does the method exist? because it is being called and apparently can't be found by php.

Comment: did you check line 389 in abstract.php?

Comment: The Yesno.php has the methods `toOptionArray()` and `toArray()` only.

Comment: Which Magento is it and what have you done before this error occurred? On which page (frontend or admin panel and the path of the URL) does this error occur?

Answer (score 1):

I also ran into this error so I'm going to assume Freejoy was trying to do the same as me, which was using custom attributes on the customer entity. The Mage_Adminhtml_Model_System_Config_Source_Yesno source model will not work with the customer entity, or any EAV entity for that matter.

Changing to Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Attribute_Source_Boolean as a source model fixed it for me.

I hope this can help others too.

Comment: Thanks but I uninstall the extension a few months ago so I'm not sure ifd your answer is correct.

Comment: That's fine :) It was for me so I thought I'd share it. Hopefully this will help somebody else someday! :P

Answer (score 0):

You've truncated your error message, this

> in Abstract.php on

should be pointing to a full file path.  Without knowing that full file path, it will be hard to diagnose the problem.

My **assumption** is Abstract.php is part of a custom module, and that custom module has instantiated a `Mage_Adminhtml_Model_System_Config_Source_Yesno` (maybe with code that looks like this)

```
$model = Mage::getModel('adminhtml/system_config_source_yesno');
$model->setAttribute();
```

and is then trying to call the `setAttribute` method -- which doesn't exist on this model.

Another possibility is you have a custom modules (or hacked core file) where you've used the model alias `adminhtml/system_config_source_yesno` in a place where Magento expects a different alias type.

Again, very hard to tell without knowing the exact file the error happens in.

Comment: This is  the whole error, I didn't check the file because it's part of Magento core.<b>Fatal error</b>:  Call to undefined method Mage_Adminhtml_Model_System_Config_Source_Yesno::setAttribute() in <b>/home/angeecom/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Eav/Model/Entity/Attribute/Abstract.php</b> on line <b>389</b><br />